# How can I make a black 3d border around an object in BGE during gameplay?

Tags: game-engine

I am trying to make a black border appear around a building in BGE (it is an RTS).  I don't know how this could be done (without drawing black around the textures and the textures on the building do not match that way) if anyone could help then that would be awesome! Thanks![image]

[image]

Comment: I drew the lines in Gimp, I did not fix it

Comment: Arguably a duplicate but I think it should be more like a selection, similar to that in the 3d viewport.